# Does sklearn DBSCAN suppose distances are normalized

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan, hyperparameters

I'm learning about DBSCAN and apparently the most important hyperparameter is eps, from sklearn documentation:

**eps float, default=0.5**

- The maximum distance between two samples for one to be considered as in the neighborhood of the other.
- This is not a maximum bound on the distances of points within a cluster.
- This is the most important DBSCAN parameter to choose appropriately for your data set and distance function.

I notice that the number 0.5 doesn't take in fact the range of the distances of our data, in other words, if I use distances from 1 to 100 will it still work the same way if I scale up those distances by a factor of x100? Or scale down by x10? Or this parameter is supposed to be used in normalized distances (`max_distance = 1`)?